# Могу ли я установить два baseUrl в Nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js

Есть тестовая и прод копии проекта. У каждой своя cms, которая ссылается на указанный baseUrl. Хочется, чтобы cms одновременно создавала страницы в обеих версиях сайта. Вижу решение в указании двух baseUrl одновременно, но не понимаю, как можно это реализовать. Перерыл кучу интернета, и нигде не нашел информации об этом.
Сейчас url указывается в config.js следующим образом

```
export const API_URL =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
        ? "http://localhost:3000/api/"
        : "https://somesite.su:8443/api/";
```